# XSD Assert equivalent in Version 1.0

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I got really excited when I spotted the assertion capability of XML/XSD, then I noticed it is version 1.1, which unfortunately we cannot use.

Is there a way of achieving assertions with 1.0?

Example, we would like for an XSD restriction to be limited to values specified in a separate element within the XML document, not the XSD schema.

With a simple restriction, it might look like:

```
  <xs:element name="recordset">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="record" type="record" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="record">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="tag" type="recordTag" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="recordTag">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="tag1" />
      <xs:enumeration value="tag2" />
      <xs:enumeration value="tag3" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

We would have liked that the tag restrictions be specified in the XML, which assertions seemed the way to create validation of these values.  Given the below change, an xs:assert element would have gone in on the *recordset* type comparing the contents of *tag* from the *record* to those of the *tagDefinitions*.

```
  <xs:element name="recordset">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="tags" type="tagDefinitions" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="record" type="record" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="record">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="tag" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="tagDefinitions">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="tag" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Is this still possible in XML 1.0?

Comment: No there isn't. That's why it was added to 1.1. If you're tied to 1.0 you could consider supplementing XSD validation with Schematron validation.

Comment: It appears the answer may lie in referential integrity (key/keyref) elements, which existed in 1.0.  Unfortunately my XML/XSD validation software I am working with at the moment does not seem to correctly validate them, so I don't know if I'm getting it right or not.

Comment: Then you should open a new question saying what you are doing and asking why it is not working as expected.